# Using JSZip to download images crashing the browser

Tags: jquery, canvas, zip

I'm using JSZip to bundle up a set of image on a page and create a zip file to store them. Here's the relevant function:

```
// Make a zip file
$("#snapLink").click(function() {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  snapFolder = zip.folder("snaps")
  $("#snapRandom img").each( function(index){
    imageLink = $(this).attr('src').substring(22);
    snapFolder.file("snap" + index + ".png", imageLink, {base64: true});
  })
  snapZip = zip.generate();
  location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+snapZip;
});
```

The images are generated from a canvas, so they aren't in the filesystem. The image sources are data urls.

This works great if there are 1-3 images to download. Once there are more than that the browser may crash at 10+ images it will definitely crash. I've tested this on Safari and Chrome on Mac so far. The images are about 120k.

Do you have any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the whole browser crash, or just the tab?

Comment: In Safari the whole browser crashes. In Chrome, it is just the tab.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and just in case other people are wondering, I am posting a solution here.

The answer was actually on the website: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function (blob) {
    saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");
});
```

It's as simple as that. Include FileSaver.js and use blob instead of base64.

The error was caused by the character limitation on href.

> The current URL length limit in chrome is 2097152 characters

I initially thought we had to use base64 to save the zip file since the images were in base64. Thankfully, we can save it as a blob and get over the 1.5Mb-ish limitation